# Admin can see the updated template and mean while normal people able to see the default one in siteground wordpress hosting

Tags: wordpress

We are building a new site using wordpress. I am facing a strange issue. Admin can able to see the updated changes in the site. But normal people can't able to see the updated template. They are only able to see the default activated template.

I tried googling, but nothing helped me so far. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

We are using siteground for the wordpress hosting. Basically, we didn't add any cache plugins. But the siteground hosting is automatically enabling the cache for WordPress sites. It will be horrible while developing the site.

So, I followed below steps to disable the cache.

1. Siteground website -> speed -> caching -> disable nginx cache and memcache
2. There is no direct option to disable the dynamic cache. So, I have installed the sg-cachepress plugin in wordpress -> plugin -> add new
3. After install, I activated the plugin
4. Then I enable and disabled the dynamic cache once for full disabling of the dynamic cache.
5. In final step I purged the cache through siteground -> speed -> cache -> dynamic cache -> purge action